# How to get GHC command as issued by Cabal/Stack?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

GHC can be used as a linter for the Neovim plugin [ale](https://github.com/w0rp/ale). The configuration uses the following command to lint a file:

```
stack ghc -- -fno-code -v0 %t
```

where `%t` is the file in question. This is fast and pretty great, however, it doesn't recognize any of the options specified in the Cabal file, and it fails to run if there are internal modules referenced in the file.

Is it possible somehow to get the GHC command that would be issued by `cabal build` or `stack build`, so that we can get the extensions/references/etc necessary to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning on verbosity should give you the information you're looking for:

```
stack build --verbose --cabal-verbose
```